# How to disable a vuejs router-link?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, routerlink

I have a single-page app that i've created using vue, and the nav links are all done using `router-link` tags. There are a couple of items in the nav that my boss wants to have in the nav but disabled so that people can get a glimpse of some features that will be coming soon. However I can't figure out how to completely disable a router-link!

`preventDefault` does nothing, `@click.native.prevent="stopClick()"` does nothing (i tried sending it to a function to see if that would prevent the click but it just calls the function and routes anyway despite the prevent), adding a `disabled` class and setting a css rule of `pointer-events: none;` does nothing. I'm not sure what else to try, is the only way around this to make the disabled links normal text and not router-links?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is still no native solution today. But there is an open PR for this on the vue-router repo : https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/pull/2098.

A workaround is to use :

```
<router-link 
  :disabled="!whateverActivatesThisLink" 
  :event="whateverActivatesThisLink ? 'click' : ''"
  to="/link"
>
  /link
</router-link>
```

Comment: deprecated in Vue Router v4 https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removal-of-event-and-tag-props-in-router-link

Answer (score 43):

You can use

```
<component
  :is="isDisabled ? 'span' : 'router-link'"
  to="/link"
>
  /link
</component>
```

Comment: Wondering why this is not the accepted answer, even 2 years later

Comment: @Luciano, this is not working for me in Vue 3 and vue-router 4.0.13. But what actually work is ` :to="isDisabled ? '' : '/link'" `

Comment: @Disorder I'm just testing it (Vue 2 vue-router 3.x.x) and your solution works, but unfortunately, it shows a link that does nothing, so in my case using `:is` looks prettier. Anyways I will take your suggestion for future Vue 3 projects. Thanks

Comment: Well no... :is works with <component>  ... so...  change <router-link to <component and it works like a charm.

Comment: If isDisabled is true, this leads to the problem that the text /link will not be shown.

Comment: So, make your own link component? This sounds silly.

Answer (score 25):

There is nothing built in, and [probably won't ever be](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/pull/2098#issuecomment-683768041). That said, what worked great for me is to use CSS.

```
<router-link to="/my-route" :class="{ disabled: someBoolean }" />
```

```css
.disabled {
    opacity: 0.5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

The opacity makes it look disabled, and the `pointer-events: none;` makes it so you don't need to also handle `:hover` styles, or set the `cursor` style.

Comment: This answer is cleanest, and everyone needs to see that Github post. Later I'd scrutinize accessibility aspects, ie is the disabled link still tabbable or do screen readers ignore it?

Answer (score 10):

I don't think there's a suitable solution for this problem since router links do not have the `disabled` attribute, but one trick would be using `tag="button"` in order to add the required attribute as follows:

```
<router-link 
     to="/link"
     tag="button"
     :disabled="true"
>
  Link
</router-link>
```

Comment: That's because `router-link` renders as html anchor tag, and `<a>` also doesn't support disabled attr. Adding `tag="button"` will make routerlink renders as button instead, and therefore the button will be naturally usable with `:disabled`.

Comment: Sadly, this will not reflect the semantics of the HTML element :(

Answer (score 9):

### Method 1: Prevent the click event

The trick is to handle an event on a capture phase and stop it from propagating up top.

```html
<router-link 
  to="/path"
  @click.native.capture.stop
>
  Go to page
</router-link>
```

Or imperatively:

```html
<router-link 
  to="/path"
  @click.native.capture="handleClick"
>
  Go to page
</router-link>
```

```js
function handleClick(event) {
  if (passesSomeCheck) event.stopPropagation();
}
```

This might be very useful if you want to get the resolved path from Vue Router to force a page load without SPA navigation.

```js
function handleClick(event) {
  if (loadWithoutSpa) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    window.location.href = event.currentTarget.href;
  };
}
```

### Method 2: Change default event to an empty string

```html
<router-link 
  to="/path"
  event
>
  Go to page
</router-link>
```

### Method 3: Use an `<a>` tag

```html
<a :href="$router.resolve(route).href">
  Go to page
</a>
```

Where route can be exactly the same thing you pass to a `to` prop on `router-link`.

Comment: Using `event.preventDefault()` instead of `event.stopPropagation()` worked for me to disable the router-link

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it since event will no longer propagate and for example would not trigger global event listeners.

Comment: FYI, `event` is deprecated in VueRouter4.

Answer (score 5):

Just set `to=""` then the link doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: This still renders a functional link that points to the current page, which is not desired.

Answer (score 3):

As I had to use `<router-link>` with custom attribute (and added custom meta to routes), I was able to solve it like this:

```
<router-link :to="route.path"
                  custom
                  v-slot="{href, route, navigate, isActive, isExactActive}">
                <a v-bind="$attrs"
                :href="href"
                @click="checkClick($event, navigate, route.meta)">
                ...
                <slot></slot>
            </a>
</router-link>
```

an then the function

```
checkClick(event: any, navigate: any, meta: { enabled: boolean }) {
            if (meta.enabled) {
                navigate(event);
                return;
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        },
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
  <router-link
   :event="whateverActivatesThisLink ? 'click' : ''"
  >
  Go to page
  </router-link>
```

Or write a cleaner code with computed:

```
  <router-link
  :event="handleWhatEverEvent"
  >
  Go to page
  </router-link>

computed: {
  handleWhatEverEvent() {
    return this.whateverActivatesThisLink ? 'click' : '';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Idk why nobody tried replace `to` prop like this:

```html
<router-link :to="disabled ? '' : '/link'">
  Link
</router-link>
```

But it's 100% work with any version of Vue and vue-router.
Another answers are not working for me with Vue 3 and vue-router 4

Comment: This still renders a functional link that points to the current page, which is not desired.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent a click you can directly access to event property of the router-link element like this (and you can use native click to do something else) :

```
<router-link 
:event="clickable ? 'click' : ''" 
@click.native="!clickable ? doOtherThing : ''" > Link </router-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set route guard per-route

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        //here you can set if condition 
        if (conditionTrue) {
          //redirect to other route
          next({path: '/bar'});
        } else {
          next();
        }
      }          
    }
  ]
})
```

Or you can set globally

```
routes: [
  {path: '/foo', component: Foo, meta:{conditionalRoute: true}}
]; 

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => { 
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.conditionalRoute)) { 
        // this route requires condition/permission to be accessed
        if (!checkCondition ) { 
            //check condition is false
            next({ path: '/'});
        } else { 
            //check condition is true
            next();
        } 
    } else { 
        next(); // Don't forget next
    } 
})
```

For more info:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards

Answer (score 0):

### If using [PrimeVue](https://primevue.org/)...

You can use `class="p-disabled"` to disable a link.

Change it dynamically as follows:

```
:class="isDisable ?  'p-disabled' : ''"
```

If you use it for a `<div>`, All the things inside the `<div></div>` will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a dynamic component to change the element, it seems to work well now that `tag` prop has been removed.

```js
<component 
    :is="disabled ? 'span' : 'router-link'"
    :to="{ path: '/path' }"
>
```

Answer (score -1):

### Update for Router v4:

Using a `boolean` variable `status` to determine if the link is active or not and passing the link (`ctalink`) as a variable as well.

Stumbled in here coming from `nuxt-link` implementation that broke with the update, so from experience this works likewise.

```
    <router-link
      v-slot="{ navigate }"
      :to="ctalink"
      custom
    >
      <div @click="status ? navigate(ctalink) : null">
        <div :class="status ? 'text-green' : 'text-gray'"> 
          Click me when active 
        </div>
      </div>
    </router-link>
```

Source: https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link-s-v-slot

Answer (score -1):

## NuxtLink (Vue Router v4)

To me what worked like a charm was the code below. This is a real code that I'm using in my application with `nuxt` and `tailwind`.

```
              <nuxt-link
                v-slot="{ navigate }"
                :to="`lesson/${lesson.lesson_id}`"
                append
                custom
              >
                <button
                  class="focus:outline-none"
                  :class="{
                    'text-gray-500 cursor-default': !lesson.released,
                  }"
                  :disabled="!lesson.released"
                  @click="navigate"
                >
                  {{ lesson.title }}
                </button>
              </nuxt-link>
```

Comment: Using `<a>` (`NuxtLink` is `<a>`) with `<button>` inside is bad. `<a>` content is 'Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant, a element descendant, or descendant with the tabindex attribute specified.' https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Answer (score -4):

use div element or span element instead of 
in combination with @click event

```
<div @click="handleRouteNavigation">
your content..
</div>
```

in script methods define

```
handleRouteNavigation(){

  if(conditionSatisfied){
      this.$router.push('/mylink')
   }

}
```

Comment: You will loose all benefits of <a> tag like open link in new tab and so on